# SCDF with Spring Batch 5 on k8s: Task Container relies on Resource created by previous Task

Tags: kubernetes, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

#### Background

I am using Spring Cloud Dataflow to execute a Task which basically is a Spring Batch Application.
This Batch Application consists of multiple jobs - one of them creates a file that can then be processed by another job. Lets call them `createFileJob` and `processFileJob` respectively.

With Spring Batch 5, the possibility to execute multiple jobs at the same time was **removed**. Consequently, to execute all 4 jobs, I have to run the Batch Application 4 times.

We are running this on Kubernetes and as you probably know, when running inside Kubernetes, SCDF executes a task in a spawned container.

Consequently, before we updated to Spring Batch 5, all of the 4 jobs were running inside the same container spawned by Spring Cloud Dataflow.

### The Issue

Now, as each task is now spawned in its own, new container, the `processFileJob` cannot find the file created by the `createFileJob` anymore, as its no longer the same container.

I'm struggling to find out how I could make it work again. I would appreciate any help on this!

Best Regards

Comment: One solution might be to add a Spring batch Tasklet that uploads file to AWS S3. In the next job, you can download the file from S3.

Comment: Why not using a single job with two steps? One that creates the file and another one that processes it? I don't see the added value of having an entire job to create a file. If you still need to use separate jobs, you need to define a persistent volume shared between jobs as a staging area.

Comment: Does Spring Cloud Dataflow support mounting a persistent volume into the containers it creates on k8s? I could not find a way to configure that